# Combining multiple import structures in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6

In my application I frequently `import` React.js as this

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

but there are classes, where I heavily use some nested Objects/or methods of nested objects like `React.Children.toArray`.

I want to eliminate duplication as much as possible, thus want to import `Children` from `react` module, or better `Children.toArray`, but still need all `React` to be imported in order for JSX to work.

Is there some way like this pseudocode:

```
import * as React, {Children: {toArray}} from 'react'
```

Specification suggests that it's not possible:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports

> ImportClause :
>
> ...
>
> ImportedDefaultBinding , NameSpaceImport
>
> ImportedDefaultBinding ,
>   NamedImports

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best you can do.

```
import React, {Children} from 'react';

const {toArray} = Children;
```

Answer (score 0):

Named imports can not be destructured, it looks the same as the destructure pattern but it is not.

You will likely get the [error](https://github.com/babel/babylon/issues/258):

> ES2015 named imports do not destructure. Use another statement for
>   destructuring after the import.

This leaves us with the option of something like:

```
import foo, { bar } from 'module';

const { nested } = bar;
```